# Can't access tomcat server on centOS VPS

Tags: linux

I got VPS (Virtual Private Server). and I want to install apache-tomcat with this server. the server's OS is CentOS 64bit. I installed through beneath steps.

**Step 1. Installing JDK**

```
    cd /usr/tmp
    wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u51-b16/jdk-8u51-linux-x64.rpm
    rpm -Uvh jdk-8u51-linux-x64.rpm
```

**Step 2. Installing Tomcat**

```
wget http://apache.tt.co.kr/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.24/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.24.tar.gz
tar xvfpz apache-tomcat-8.0.24.tar.gz
mv apache-tomcat-8.0.24 /usr/local/tomcat
```

**Step 3. Adding tomcat service** 
wrote beneath shell code and save into /etc/rc.d/init.d/
and change permission by 'chmod 755 /etc/rc.d/init.d/tomcat'

```
#!/bin/sh
# Startup script for Tomcat
#
# chkconfig: 35 85 15
# description: apache tomcat 6.x
#
# processname: tomcat
#
# Source function library.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
export CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$CATALINA_HOME/bin
# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
start)
echo -n "Starting tomcat: "
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh start
echo
;;
stop)
echo -n "Shutting down tomcat: "
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh stop
echo
;;
restart)
$0 stop
sleep 2
$0 start
;;
*)
echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
exit 1
esac
exit 0
```

**Step 4. Run service**

```
chkconfig –add tomcat
service tomcat start
```

But... I couldn't see cat on server:8080...
So I found some document saying open 8080 port on iptables.
so I adding this quote

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

But things not changed. still I can't access this server at externally. 
Even if I stop iptables, iptables6, Can't acess.

```
Server IP : 168.92.122.39   Domain : 39.vs.woobi.co.kr
FTP 182.162.94.35:53921 -> 192.168.122.39:21
SSH 182.162.94.35:53922 -> 192.168.122.39:22
MYSQL 182.162.94.35:53906 -> 192.168.122.39:3306
```

I don't know what is problem. I spend so many time with this. please help me!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using the `iptables` command you specified, try the `firewall-cmd` command (CentOS 7) or `lokkit` (CentOS 6)

```
# CentOS 6
lokkit -p 8080:tcp

# CentOS 7
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Also check the documentation of your VPS provider. It may be that you must open/forward the port in their user interface as well. I know for example that Amazon requires this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. my CentOS is 6.4 and, I installed lokkit and run lokkit -p 8080:tcp. but nothing changed. and I want to know more one, Is it proper access to 182.162.94.35:8080 ???? or 168.92.122.39:8080? Do you know?

Comment: You cannot reach a 192.168.* address from the internet. Check with the documentation of your VPS how you can find the internet-facing IP address.

Comment: Hey I got it. I found docs that you said. "Accessing HTTP : http://182.162.94.35:80" . success. but I don't know why it is use not 8080 port but 80 port . Do you know?? anyway Thanks!

Comment: And not a cat image on http://182.162.94.35:80  just apache server... it is worked?... or default option..? I don't know it...

Comment: Port 80 is standard for a webserver, but requires your program to run as root. Since it is unwise to run Tomcat as root, 8080 is a good choice.

Comment: People says it is success to see cat image on browser. How can I see the cat? And Is your saying 80 port for Apache, and 8080 port for Tomcat? Can you answer last one question? Very Thanks. Good Night!

Comment: This is getting off topic, but port 80 for Apache and 8080 for Tomcat is a common setup. I don't think you need Apache, just go to http://[ip]:8080 and you should see the cat.

Comment: If you have further questions about this topic, please just post a new question on this site.

Comment: I have a new 1&1 VPS, and I had to add a rule for the default 8080 port to work, although still trying to get 80 working...