# Tomcat not working but apache works. on CentOs 6.x

Tags: java, linux, apache, tomcat

Tomcat not working but apache works. on CentOs 6.x

1. I Installed jdk, tomcat, and several steps through [Can't access tomcat server on centOS VPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31680947/cant-access-tomcat-server-on-centos-vps).
2. I can access Apache page, but tomcat's doesn't.

**Apache : http://182.162.94.35/ (Can see the sample page)**

**Tomcat : http://182.162.94.35:8080 (Error)**

3. I don't know what is problem... People says usually I need to change tomcat's port 8080 to another, so I tried but same.
4. Here is catalina.log...

   ```
   29-Jul-2015 01:37:12.320 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.24
   29-Jul-2015 01:37:12.327 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jul 1 2015 20:19:55 UTC
   29-Jul-2015 01:37:12.327 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.24.0
   29-Jul-2015 01:37:12.327 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
   29-Jul-2015 01:37:12.327 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64
   29-Jul-2015 01:37:12.327 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
   29-Jul-2015 01:37:12.328 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_51/jre
   29-Jul-2015 01:37:12.328 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_51-b16
   29-Jul-2015 01:37:12.328 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
   29-Jul-2015 01:37:12.328 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
   29-Jul-2015 01:37:12.335 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
   29-Jul-2015 01:37:12.337 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
   29-Jul-2015 01:37:12.337 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
   29-Jul-2015 01:37:12.338 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/tomcat/endorsed
   29-Jul-2015 01:37:12.338 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
   29-Jul-2015 01:37:12.339 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
   29-Jul-2015 01:37:12.339 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp
   29-Jul-2015 01:37:12.340 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
   29-Jul-2015 01:37:12.898 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
   29-Jul-2015 01:37:12.954 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
   java.net.BindException: Address already in use
       at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
   "catalina.out" 386L, 47802C
   ```

and I see also these errors...

```
29-Jul-2015 01:37:12.954 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use


29-Jul-2015 01:37:12.961 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
```

Does anyone who can solve this...? Thanks.

Comment: There might be another tomcat instance running. Try shutting it down or change the Connector port=”8080″  to a different port in server.xml.

Comment: @singhr Hi...I tried but facing same problem.

Comment: I see. Did you restart both tomcat and apache? Need to start tomcat before apache.

Answer (score 0):

Obsequiously,your log says the problems is due to the port is busy. So, as you yourself said, you should change the port. I am sure you correctly didn't change the port.

please take a look at following link: "http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/how-to-change-tomcat-default-port/" and make sure your change is applied. you can verify this by looking at log files.